# What to do when finding errors in my submitted bachelor thesis?

Tags: thesis

I have just submitted my bachelor thesis. However, I found right now in total two mistakes. One is that a table is missing, although this table is not that important. The other is one sentence ends in the half way. I haven't found out them since I was too busy at that time with another exam. Would my bachelorthesis fail due to these reasons?

Comment: Does your system permit corrections? Will your advisor have any influence if you just inform them of the mistakes along with a correction?

Comment: I'm not really sure about this since the ddl of my thesis was yesterday. I'll check this. Just don't know how serious a missing table can be.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to your advisor and let them know that you found the errors. Have a corrected version ready for them. It can't hurt and might help.

People make mistakes. Other people recognize that. People especially make mistakes at a pending deadline. But, on the other hand, sloppiness isn't good and you may suffer for it.

But, if it is otherwise good and sound, failure seems like a bit too far to go.

Comment: I think failure is much more than a bit too far. I would suspect no real consequence whatever. Lesson learned: don't crowd a deadline.

Comment: Also, errors are to be expected. Many authors maintain a list of errata for each substantial paper. It's reasonable to email that to your supervisor, and ask if they want them incorporated into the paper if its yet to be examined. Providing the list at least makes them aware you know of the errors. Once examined or published, keep the list independently of the paper -- don't incorporate any further errata. After a few years write a short introduction to the errata placing the paper in its historical context (eg, are there now different approaches, has your view changed).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions here. I'll tell it to my advisor and prepare a new version of it as well as give a errate for it. See if it works tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the rest looks. If the rest is great, those mistakes might not matter at all. If it is borderline otherwise, it might tip it over to the fail grade.